# Correcting PATH after dist upgrade?

Tags: debian, upgrade, path, troubleshooting

After a dist upgrade (Debian 9 to Debian 10) some things stopped working.

For example, `iwconfig`, `losetup`, `ifconfig`, `poweroff`, `pm-hibernate`.

These commands work if I type the full path like `/sbin/iwconfig`

My `PATH` is `/home/<myusername>/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/home/<myusername>/.local/bin`

Should I just change the path to add `/sbin` `/usr/sbin` to it?

Equally, emacs does not find `/home/<myusername>/.emacs`, should I just add my home directory to the path?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just change the path to add /sbin /usr/sbin to it?

Yes. You should add `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/local/sbin` to your PATH.

[What's new in the Buster release?](https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster)

> Put the system administration directories (`/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/local/sbin`) in your regular account's PATH (see [EnvironmentVariables](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables) for help with this).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation on such case (file names may vary, since the closest I have to a Debian machine right now is an Ubuntu one, which is still Debian based).

1. Keep "user defined" applications in the "user defined" path variable. On a machine that has multiple users, if they are added to the "system wide" path, these applications are theoretically visible to all other users, even though they could possibly have no permissions to execute if they are not part of the same groups as you are, for instance. The `/home/<myusername>/.emacs` application could be added to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file by appending to it the line below.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/<USER>/<APPLICATION_PATH>
```

2. Keep "system wide" applications in the "system wide" path. On a machine that has multiple users, if they are added to the "user defined" path, these applications are not visible to other users. Your `/sbin/<APPLICATION_PATH>` application could be added to `/etc/profile` file by appending to it the line below.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin/
```

The `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile` files are read on a "per logon" or "per terminal session" basis (more details [here](https://serverfault.com/a/261807/447098)), so they are not suitable for "system wide" applications that multiple users must have access to, in which case the `/etc/profile` file can be more appropriate (more details [here](https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables#Using_text_console)).

Comment: P.S.: In addition, notice that `/sbin` folder is intended to contain applications that only the administrator could execute, as stated [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s1-filesystem-fhs.html#s3-filesystem-sbin). So, it is worth checking if the super user still can execute these applications after the update :)

Comment: [UPDATE] Just for correctness sake, @GAD3R [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518943/264443) is more accurate in regard of the administrative applications for this release of Debian, indeed in the documentation page that referred on his answer it is the recomendation. Thanks for pointing out!